# custom module not found when debugging in VSCode Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I currently have a python project running with the current launch config.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}\\project_code"}
        }
    ]
}
```

The python file that I am debugging is in a different folder "${workspaceRoot}\project_code\check_files" which imports modules from a separate folder "${workspaceRoot}\project_code\src"

When I am running the file without debugging, it works however when I try to run it with the debugger, the module that I am trying to import from the src folder is not found. I tried googling for a solution but can't seem to find one that works. Hence, appreciate if somebody can provide some guidance on what should I do?

**UPDATE**

added directory structure for reference. Also, I have updated the deprecated references as well. Thanks for pointing that out [JialeDu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19133920/jialedu)

```
project_name (VS code folder is opened at this directory)
 - project_code
   - py_files (the file that I am trying to run is here)
   - modules (the module location that I am trying to load)
```

Comment: what are you saying? What is the workspace folder you have open now? Provide your directory structure and show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
.

Comment: Why using `${workspaceRoot}` variable in *launch.json*, it is deprecated. Please use `${workspaceFolder}`.  [Link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_why-isnt-workspaceroot-documented).

Comment: @JialeDu thanks for pointing out the deprecated var reference. updated original post. Also, have modified the post with additional information on the problem that I am facing

Comment: What import method do you use? Would you mind adding `import sys
sys.path.append("./project_code")` to the top of your code?

Comment: Any updates here?

Comment: hey @JialeDu. Thanks for the follow up, I ended up taking the import sys approach (was trying to avoid it). Also, what do you mean by the import approach?

Comment: I mean what does your import statement look like?